# Extract patches at given location from a PyTorch Tensor

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor, indices

I have a 3D tensor containing grayscales images. In this tensor, the first dimension is representing the number of grayscale images. The remaining 2 dimensions are height and width respectively.

For each image, I have a pixel location say (x, y). Therefore, if there are 4 images, then corresponding to each image, I have an (x, y) pixel location.

I want to extract a patch from each image (let say 3x3 patch, i.e., 1 pixel up, 1 pixel down, 1 pixel left, 1 pixel right) which is centered around the given pixel location.

My current approach is shown below:

```
# define our batch having 4 grayscale images 
>>> d = torch.rand(4, 64, 64)

# define pixel location for each image
>>> xy = torch.tensor([(15, 21), (30, 59), (40, 5), (20, 25)])
>>> x, y = xy.T

# m = 1 means a patch of 3x3 centered around given pixel location
>>> m = 1

# loop through each image and stack the result
>>> o = torch.stack([di[xi - m : xi + m + 1, yi - m : yi + m + 1] for di, xi, yi in zip(d, x, y)])
>>> o.size()
torch.Size([4, 3, 3])
```

**My concern is that the current approach uses a `for` loop which may not be the optimal way. Is there exist a better PyTorch way of doing the same?**

Comment: How do you plan to handle edge cases? For instance, what would you expect if `x, y = 0, 0`?

Comment: @Berriel: The edge cases can be ignored. Because the pixel locations are never going to be in that range (in this particular case only).

Comment: Any suggestions, please. PyTorch functions such as [torch.gather](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) and [torch.index_select](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html) are applied to one dimension at a time.